# How to count occurences in a Skiplist

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

If we have an sorted skiplist how can we count the occurences if it is sorted on a effective way?
Occurence of the same element in the skiplist?

Comment: Does the input set of elements contains repetitions or are they all distinct?

Comment: They can contain same elements and not a set!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the skip list is constructed with probability parameter $p$. Suppose you want to find the number of occurrences of an element $e$ in the skip list.

Algorithm: Perform a standard search of $e$ in the skip list. Suppose, the element is found at level $i$. Then, the element must also appear in each of the levels from $1$ to $i$ since a level $j$ is a subset of level $i$ if $j < i$.

To count the number of occurrences of the element at any such level, the algorithm makes a linear scan to left and right from the current position.  Since each level is sorted, the algorithm stops once it finds an element different from $e$. This takes time $O(p_j)$, where $p_j$ is the number of occurrences of element $e$ at $j^{th}$ level.

Overall time is: search time + $\sum_{j = 1}^{i} O(p_j)$ =  search time + $p_{e}$, where $p_e$ is the total number of occurrences of element $e$ in the skip list.

If the element $e$ has $t$ copies in the input set, then the expected number of times it appears in the skip list is $t /p$. That is $\mathbb{E}[p_e] = t/p$. Also, the expected search time in a skip list is [$O(\frac{1}{p} \cdot \log_{1/p} n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Description).  Therefore, the overall search time becomes $O(\frac{1}{p} \cdot \log_{1/p} n) + O(t/p)$.